# JDateChooser setDate call ends execution unexpectedly

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I am using Toeder `JDateChooser` in my stand-alone Java application as seen in the code snippet below. The purpose here is:

1. To shift the the calendar instance to a desired week of the year and then
2. To set the start-date and the end-date of the desired week accordingly. These dates are kept in two JDateChooser instances, namely `jDateChooserBookBegin` and `jDateChooserBookEnd`.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentWeekOfYear = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int desiredWeekOfYear = jComboBookWeekMainPanel.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, c.getFirstDayOfWeek());

for (int i = currentWeekOfYear; i < desiredWeekOfYear; i++) {
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7); //e.g. set to next Monday
}
jDateChooserBookBegin.setDate(c.getTime()); // ***** HERE *****

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); //set to the end of week e.g. Sunday
jDateChooserBookEnd.setDate(c.getTime());
```

Problem: Let's say the above snippet is executed within a method. I checked the code in debug mode in neatbeans and I swear when the execution reaches the line marked with a dashed arrow, the rest of the lines are not executed at all and the encapsulating method returns immediately to the caller. This causes `jDateChooserBookEnd` not to be set to the proper date and my program behaves in an undesired fashion as a result.

Question: Why does the `setDate` method of the `JDateChooser` class cause the rest of the lines not to be executed by returning to the caller? Is there a known bug on this? Do you have any clue? This looks rather impossible but it's happening. I am using Java 6.

---

The full method content is available below. The above snippet is a simplified version of what you see below. In the program, I have two jButtons named next week and previous week. Whenever one of these buttons is clicked the relevant actionPerformed method makes a call to the below method.

```
private void update_DateFieldsInMainPanel() { 
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentWeekOfYear = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); 
    int desiredWeekOfYear = jComboBookWeekMainPanel.getSelectedIndex() + 1;             c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, c.getFirstDayOfWeek()); 

    if (desiredWeekOfYear ==currentWeekOfYear) {                             
        jDateChooserBokMainFrom.setDate(c.getTime());        
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); 
        jDateChooserBokMainTill.setDate(c.getTime());   
    } 
    else if (desiredWeekOfYear > currentWeekOfYear) { 
        for (int i = currentWeekOfYear; i < desiredWeekOfYear; i++) { 
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7); 
        } 
        jDateChooserBokMainFrom.setDate(c.getTime()); 
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); 
        jDateChooserBokMainTill.setDate(c.getTime()); 
    }
    else { 
        for (int i = currentWeekOfYear; i > desiredWeekOfYear; i--) { 
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -7); 
        }
        jDateChooserBokMainFrom.setDate(c.getTime());   
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6); 
        jDateChooserBokMainTill.setDate(c.getTime());  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this done in a try/catch block? If so, are you catching exceptions? Do any exceptions get thrown?

Comment: No try/catch is present and absolutely no exception is thrown.

Comment: This is smelling like an exception is occurring somewhere somehow. But with just the information presented, it's hard to say.

Comment: Hard to say without your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), but you might try the fixes mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jcalendar/info).

Comment: I have two jButtons like next week and previous week. Whenever one of these buttons is clicked the relevant actionPerformed method makes a call to the below method. The code snippet I had written previously is a simplified version of this method. The setDate method normally does not throw an exception, I did not check anything on that within a try/catch. Perhaps you can think of a runtime exception which interrupts the entire program, which is not the case in the program I wrote.

Comment: private void update_DateFieldsInMainPanel() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentWeekOfYear = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        int desiredWeekOfYear = jComboBookWeekMainPanel.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, c.getFirstDayOfWeek());

        if (desiredWeekOfYear == currentWeekOfYear) {
            jDateChooserBokMainFrom.setDate(c.getTime());
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
            jDateChooserBokMainTill.setDate(c.getTime());

Comment: } else if (desiredWeekOfYear > currentWeekOfYear) {
            for (int i = currentWeekOfYear; i < desiredWeekOfYear; i++) {
                c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);
            }
            jDateChooserBokMainFrom.setDate(c.getTime());

            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
            jDateChooserBokMainTill.setDate(c.getTime());
        } else {
            for (int i = currentWeekOfYear; i > desiredWeekOfYear; i--) {
                c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -7);
            }
            jDateChooserBokMainFrom.setDate(c.getTime());

Comment: c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
            jDateChooserBokMainTill.setDate(c.getTime());
        }
    }

Comment: I am sorry the page did not let me put the whole method code in one comment.

Comment: You can edit your question to include revised code; this will make it easier to read, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch **Throwable** instead of Exception.

Comment: I have added a try catch Throwable but even that has not been caught. :(